# moderncv and babel spanish cause "Missing \endcsname..." error

Tags: errors, babel, moderncv, spanish

When I run the following code it compiles as expected:

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt
 ,a4paper
 ,sans
]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel} 

% Personal Data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}
\address{city}{state}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{extrainfo}
\quote{somequote}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{First section}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{Prueba}{Alimentación}{alimentaci'on}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Uncommenting `\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel}` generates the following error (pasting here only the first part):

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.  \protect l.22
>   \phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890} The control sequence marked  should not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

If I then comment out the `\phone` lines (so `babel` is still uncommented) it runs fine. Furthermore, using babel with another language (e.g. ngerman) and the `\phone` lines, also works fine.

Can anybody tell me waht's going on? Why can't I have both babel spanish and `\phone` uncommented?

I use moderncv 1.5.1, Texlive 2012.20120611-5 and Texmaker 3.4 on Linux Mint Debian edition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `babel` module for Spanish redefines `\roman` to use small caps and in many places `moderncv` uses `\roman` for building indexed macros, basically by doing

```
\csname xyz\roman{counter}\endcsname
```

which won't work if `\roman` is redefined in that way.

Solution: add the `es-lcroman` option when loading `babel`:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
```

I'm not sure that `activeacute` is really necessary with UTF-8 input. I wouldn't use `~` for the phone numbers: a normal space seems sufficient.

---

A different strategy, if `es-scroman` is needed, is to patch all the `moderncv` commands that use `\roman`:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
 sans,
]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel} 

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd*{\endcvcolumns}
 {\c{roman}\cB.tmpiteratorcounter\cE.}
 {\c{romannumeral}\c{c@tmpiteratorcounter}}
 {}{}
\regexpatchcmd*{\cvcolumn}
 {\c{roman}\cB.cvcolumnscounter\cE.}
 {\c{roman}\c{c@cvcolumnscounter}}
 {}{}
\regexpatchcmd*{\collectionadd}
 {\c{roman}\cB.(collection@\cP.2@count)\cE.}
 {\c{romannumeral}\c{csname}c@\1\c{endcsname}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

% Personal Data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}
\address{city}{state}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (234) 567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2 (345) 678 901}
\phone[fax]{+3 (456) 789 012}
\email{john@doe.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{extrainfo}
\quote{somequote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{First section}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{Prueba}{Alimentación}{alimentaci'on}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

---

A request for bug fix should be filed to the maintainer of `moderncv`. The macros involved are

1. `\endcvcolumns` which is defined by `\newenvironment{cvcolumns}`, where the occurrences of

   ```
   \roman{tmpiteratorcounter}
   ```

   should become

   ```
   \romannumeral\c@tmpiteratorcounter
   ```
2. `\cvcolumn`, where the occurrences of

   ```
   \roman{cvcolumnscounter}
   ```

   should become

   ```
   \romannumeral\c@cvcolumnscounter
   ```
3. `\collectionadd` (in `moderncvcollection.sty`), where the occurrences of

   ```
   \roman{collection@#2@count}
   ```

   should become

   ```
   \romannumeral\csname c@collection@#2@count\endcsname
   ```

---

A similar problem that shows when `\moderncvstyle{banking}` is used can be solved by adding

```
\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{%
    {\quad{\rmfamily\textbullet}\quad}}
```

The style uses `~~~` instead of `\quad` and, due to how the Spanish module of `babel` treats `~`, using this in the title breaks the compilation. I believe that `\quad` or `\hspace{...}` should be used anyway: leave sequences of spaces to word processors, LaTeX can do better. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you @egreg. That worked just fine. I ended up using `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman,activeacute]{babel}`. I mix in the `activeacute` so I get properly accented words when I input something like `alimentaci'on`. I have an English keyboard with which I type a lot of Spanish.

Comment: @refp16 Will you make a bug report? I've listed the necessary changes to be made to `moderncv.cls` and `moderncvcollection.sty`. With TeX Live 2012 you don't have `regexpatch`, I believe; but I tested the changes and they work.

Comment: I filed the bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/moderncv/+bug/1243455 . Thanks.

Comment: If `\moderncvstyle{classic}` is changed to `\moderncvstyle{banking}`, for example, both solutions (one with `es-lcroman`, the other with `es-scroman`) break with a similar error. Can someone suggest a fix for this? @egreg

Comment: @refp16 I added the workaround for `banking`

Answer (score 1):

The propossed solution is not complete. You will run into the same problem in other cv-scripts. Load spanish-babel as:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting,es-noshorthands]{babel}
```

or

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting,es-noshorthands,activeacute]{babel}
```

in case you write María as `Mar'ia`. 
The short-hands interfere with `moderncv`.